# Find out only completely visible list items in android- list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to find out the position or ids related to a `ListView's` items: only those ones which are completely visible on the screen.
Using `listview.getFirstVisibleposition` and `listview.getLastVisibleposition` takes partial list items into account.

Comment: You need to improve this question a little: add some code so people see what you've done and tried; also, it is unclear what you are asking; and it would be better if you added other tags (e.g.: `android`) to catch more attention.

Comment: Do you want to show only visible items without scrolling of your listview?

Comment: @Piyush i want to find only the entirely visible ListView's items on screen not the partially visible ones every time when ListView is scrolled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this, but here are the pieces of the framework that I believe will get you to what you're looking for (at least this is what I'd try first)

1. As you've stated, you should get the last visible position from the list view using `ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()`
2. You can then access the View representing this position using `ListView.getChildAt(position)`
3. You now have a reference to the view, which you can call a combination of `View.getLocationOnScreen(location)` and `View.getHeight()`
4. Also call `View.getLocationOnScreen(location)` and `View.getHeight()` on the ListView.  `y + height` of the `View` should be less than or equal to `y + height` of the `ListView` if it is fully visible.

Answer (score 3):

I followed  a little bit similar approach as suggested by Rich, to suit my requirement which was to fetch completely visible items on screen when List View is scrolled every time.

This is what i did

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    //Loop to get tids of all completely visible List View's item scrolled on screen
    for (int listItemIndex = 0; listItemIndex <= getListView().getLastVisiblePosition() - getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition(); listItemIndex++) {

        View listItem = getListView().getChildAt(listItemIndex);
        TextView tvNewPostLabel = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tvNewPostLabel);
        if (tvNewPostLabel != null && tvNewPostLabel.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            int listTid = (int) tvNewPostLabel.getTag();
            if (listItem.getBottom() < getListView().getHeight()) {//If List View's item is not partially visible
                listItemTids.add(listTid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is listItemTids in this? Can you please explain?

Comment: I had a **New** label attached to all the newer posts in my Newsfeed screen. My requirement was to remove new label from posts whenever user scrolled to those post. 
The catch was to remove label only if the post was completely visible on screen when user scroll to it.

**listTid** is actually the post id. Every list item which is visible completely on screen , I am adding its **listTid** in a HashSet<Integer> which is **listItemTids**.

Later using this HashSet of tids to call my request to make these post as read.